# fade out in mozilla/IE wont work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, fadeout

here's one plugin i am trying to create

http://jsfiddle.net/9FcN3/2/

it works perfectly in chrome, but i cant get it working in Firefox and IE.. in Firefox second fade out does it without animation(simply disappears), and in IE its complete mess(starts function without click and doesn't animate fades)

can you please at least push me in right direction on this?

trying to get it working in IE version 9

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="thmb"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="player">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ytplayer.js"  charset="utf-8></script>

</div>
```

JS:

```
  $('#thmb').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut('slow', timeout());
    function timeout(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#logo').fadeOut('slow',play());
    },2000);
    }
  });

 function play() {
   if (player) {
     player.playVideo();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please always specify the browser versions you need to support; particularly for IE this is important, as IE8 and earlier has extremely poor support for opacity, meaning that fading effects can be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function play,not assigning a reference to it.

```
$('#logo').fadeOut('slow',play());
```

needs to be

```
$('#logo').fadeOut('slow',play);
```

The other problem you have with IE is CSS. The layers are not being positioned the way you think they are. You should be setting `wmode: "opaque"`

Comment: well $('#logo').fadeOut('slow',play); didn't make any difference.. still second fade out doesn't animate in Firefox..
and can you please tell me a bit more about wmode, how should i use it in this situation?